# "Fixing print syntax error within Python if statement"

Tags: python, syntax

Doing a small project - simple restaurant menu ordering code. Got the top section to work. Why is Python giving me a syntax error for this simple print statement?

```
manager_func = input("Would you like to close the store for the day? Enter Y or N")
    if manager_func == "Y":
        continueOrder == False
        perc = input("What percentage of the daily takings is profit? Enter number from 1 to 99")
        final_total = (sum(day_totals) * (perc / 100)
        print('Here are the totals for each order', day_totals)
        print('And the corresponding order codes', day_orders)
        print('The total profit with a % taking of', perc, 'is', final_total)
    else:
        continueOrder == True
```

On line 6, it gives me a print syntax error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On line 5 you have 3 open brackets, but only 2 closing:

```
final_total = (sum(day_totals) * (perc / 100)
```

should be

```
final_total = (sum(day_totals) * (perc / 100))
```

Edit:

Also, line 3 isn't doing what you'd expect it to. Since you are using `==`, you are checking for equality, not assigning a value.

```
econtinueOrder == False
```

should be

```
continueOrder = False
```

and also line 10:

```
continueOrder == True
```

should be

```
continueOrder = True
```